# obtain relative mouse input/movements in Python such

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, python-imaging-library, mouse

I am trying to track my mouse movement in a fullscreen game so that I can take that movement and essentially draw my recoil control pattern as I shoot. I have figured out what I need to do for the visualization aspect of the code, but I cant seem to get accurate outputs with direct mouse input.

Here is the code I used:

```
import winput, time, math



def mouse_callback( event ):
    if event.action == winput.WM_LBUTTONDOWN: # prints the L-mouse-button position when pressed
        global pressed_time
        pressed_time=event.time
        print("[LMB] pressed at {}".format( event.position ))

    if event.action == winput.WM_LBUTTONUP: # prints the R-mouse-button position when pressed
        print("[LMB] released at {}".format( event.position ))

    if event.action == winput.WM_LBUTTONUP: # prints the time in MS the L-mouse-button was released from when it was initially pressed
        released_time = event.time
        final_time = (released_time-pressed_time)
        #print("[LMB] released {}ms later.".format( final_time))
        print("---")
        
def keyboard_callback( event ):
    if event.vkCode == winput.VK_ESCAPE: # quit on pressing escape
        winput.stop()
#    if event.action == winput.WM_KEYDOWN: # prints pre-defined keys when pressed
#        if event.vkCode == 87:
 #           print("W")
  #      if event.vkCode == 65:
   #         print("A")
    #    if event.vkCode == 83:
     #       print("S")
      #  if event.vkCode == 68:
       #     print("D")
#        print(event.vkCode)

print("Press escape to quit")
    
# hook input    
winput.hook_mouse( mouse_callback )
winput.hook_keyboard( keyboard_callback )

# enter message loop
try:
    while 1:
        #time.sleep(1./150)
        msg = (winput.get_message())
        if msg:
            break
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

# remove input hook
winput.unhook_mouse()
winput.unhook_keyboard()
```

This is the code I tried, it work in any game where you simply move your cursor around, but since FPS and other fullscreen games use lock the cursor at the center of your screen therefore making my simple coordinate plotting with a smoothing formula wont work. I'm stumped, all the libraries I've looked at so far are focused on outputting mouse movements not measuring the input, its unclear whether they can be used in that manner though. I am still trying out some ideas and I think I may have made a little progress but any advice would be greatly appreciated.

How can I record mouse movement if the game locks the mouse at a position?

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61915912/how-can-i-make-the-cursor-move-in-game-using-python-ex-first-shooter-shooting